# Should I use SVG or PNG for my animated videos?

Tags: animation, file-formats, animation-rendering

I'm currently building animations which will be exported into videos.
In some case I have stills in the background that won't change over the whole duration.

Question: Are there any differences in exported video size when using SVG compared to PNG for my still background?
As far as I know, the video will render them in a fixed resolution anyways (and thus it won't affect file size)?
Does it change when using different container formats?